# Prevent JQuery loaded example script from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, xss

I have a page where I want it to dump the javascript that describes it into a `<code>` block.  The trouble is if I use `$('pre code').html(data);` the browser interprets tags in the scripts string literals and the formatting breaks. Conversely if I use `$('pre code').text(data);` then my script is executed, resulting in the page being rendered twice and duplicating some elements.

I know this is a strange use case, but is there any canonical solution to this kind of problem?  My current solution is just to render the box and execute the script at the same time.

```
$.get("index.js", function(data, status)
{
    //Populate the code box and rn the page javascript at the same time
    //It seems to be impossible to set the text without making the javascript execute
    $('pre code').text(data);
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `dataType` property to `text` on the `jQuery.get()` call:

```
$.get("index.js", function(data, status){
    $('pre code').html(data);
},"text"); // add this
```

The [`dataType`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) property is:

> The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

Not a great demonstration since nothing would be executed anyway, [but here's the example above](https://jsfiddle.net/s57unpcd/) getting the jQuery library as plain text

Answer (score 0):

Pre is for multiline and code is for single line code snippets.  This isn't exactly the code you're looking for, but it illustrates an example.  White space is not conserved in a code tag.  So, all you need is a pre tag to display all of your lines of code.  Additionally, **very important** that you replace < and > with &gt and &lt, otherwise any inline HTML you have in your JavaScript file will be executed (or you could just user the .text function).

```
<pre></pre>

<code>
tset
stest
tset
</code>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.get("test.js",function (data) {
    $("pre").html(data.replace(/\</g,"&lt;").replace(/\>/g,"&gt;"));
});

</script>
```